# With Django/SQL when should I use Abstract models vs 1-to-1 connections?

Tags: python, sql, django, inheritance, database-design

So, my current situation is a voting website, many things can be voted on

- `Post`
- `Comment`
- several other things (and more in the future)

I have a `Voteable` class which in my current (pre-django, system without inheritance) design is connected to `Post`, `Comment` and other models with a 1-to-1 connection, also a `Vote` class which happily points at the `Voteable`.

But Django lets us do inheritance, so I could transform `Voteable` into an `abstract` class which `Post`, `Comment`, or other items I want to be able to vote on inherit.

It looks like this would give me easier, faster queries - but at the cost of my `Vote` class either having to become abstract, and a different type of connection to the models inheriting `Voteable`... or use a Generic Foreign Key to point at the models based `Voteable`?

Comment: If u want to vote different classes and you dont want to make a new vote class foreach model, or vote classe with many foreign keys with blank=true you are looking for Generic Foreign Keys https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

Comment: Sure - I am aware that'd work (see the last line of my question!) I am asking about the merits of each method, particularly in performance and maintainability.